# How to add underline of a <td> text in HTML5

Tags: html

I am using HTML5, when I use `<u></u>` tag for underline, it says that it is unsupported by HTML5. What can I use in place of this for underlining?

Comment: You need to use CSS, I _highly_ recommend learning it properly. [MDN has a decent up-to-date tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Getting_Started). And [never use w3schools](http://w3fools.com).

Comment: I don't know what "it" is, but "it" is wrong. The `<u>` element is valid in HTML5. See http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/text-level-semantics.html#the-u-element. However, unless you are using the element in accordance with the pretty narrow use cases defined for the element, you should be using CSS as described in the answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for the `text-decoration` directive in CSS. As underlined text is a matter of styling and not of layout, it is better relegated to a stylesheet.

Which can be use as such, which will apply the style to all `<td>` elements on the page

```
td {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

In CSS if you want a more targeted method of apply style, one way to go about this is with the class attribute of a tag `<td class="className">`. In CSS classes are defined with a leading full-stop.

```
.className {
    /* relevant style */
}
```

so in the case of underlining you specific `<td>` tags. A method would be:

```
.underline {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

<td class="underline">Here be underline</td><td>Here not be underline</td> ...
```

Further information on the form and ussage of CSS can he found at [Css Basics](http://www.cssbasics.com/)

Comment: and how to use it, if i want to underline only one td, not all , as i have <td>${user.status}</td>
        <td><u>${user.action}</u></td>

Comment: In this case, you can use a class; e.g. `<td>${user.status}</td><td class="action">${user.action}</td>`.  Then replace `td` with `td.action`, in Mimisbrunnr's example.  `td.action` means "a `td` tag with the class `action`".

Answer (score 0):

One approch to this

```
<td><span class='underline'>${user.status}</span></td>
 <td><u>${user.action}</u></td>
```

In css create a class

```
.underline {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```